# 403 Forbidden Access , Deploying website on Remote Server

Tags: asp.net

I am trying it from 3 days but couldn't  succeed . when i Upload the site to Remote Server i am getting this 403 error . the Site i have tested on my local IIS  its work fine but when i am trying to access it from the remote server it give me error. 
I have Published the ASP.NET solution in Visual Studio 2012. then tested in local iis . I have uploaded  an index.html page for test to the server but its works fine but when i want to access aspx pages it not working and 403 and 404 errors are alerting . Please give me some solution i don't know more how to fix it . my Application is in DotNet FrameWork 4.0 and the remote server Framework version is 4.0.30319.17929. What Change i should do on the remote server if needed

Comment: Have you searched on 403 error? It's an 'access denied' error. Do you have local access to the IIS server to troubleshoot?

Comment: @ElectricLlama , yes i have access on local iis and its work fine but how to get acces for the this application on remote server, i have the FTP rights

Comment: @ElectricLlama , And i am searching this issue since last 3 days .

Comment: You can't remote into the IIS server and check everything locally? This will be difficult to troubleshoot without that. Who set up and configured the server? Deos an .ASPX page in exactly the same location as your .HTML page throw the error?

Comment: yes withen Pages directory i put both the Html and APSX pages but Html Pages accesses and are opening and aspx pages not opening and give me 403 , and as i mention that i tested it on local IIS it work fine . but give me issues in remote server ...

Comment: You need to find the 'administrator' of this system and find out how the IIS is setup. The folder mightn't set up as an application. The application pool identity might not have sufficient access.